# Customizing JBOSS 6.2 EAP logging

Tags: logging, log4j, jboss-eap-6

Developing a web application using JBOSS 6.2 EAP as the Application server. Trying to customize the the logging. Want to create different logs for different modules in specified locations.

Did some home work and tried to add

```
periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FOO_BAR_FILE">
    <formatter>
        <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
    </formatter>
    <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="foo_bar_file.log"/>
    <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
    <append value="true"/>
</periodic-rotating-file-handler>
```

in the profile section of standalone.xml

and added the logger also in the same file

```
<logger category="com..org.Commets">
    <level name="INFO"/>
    <handlers>
        <handler name="FOO_BAR_FILE"/>
    </handlers>
</logger>
```

Also, cant able to find the log4j.xml in the jboss folder.
New to JBoss , guess  missing something or  going in the wrong way. Can somebody help in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JBoss EAP 6.x does not use log4j. It uses JBoss Log Manager which is an extension of J.U.L.

With regards to your configuration what you have should work just fine. Assuming of course you have a category named `com..org.Comments`.

If you want each deployment to have their own logging configuration have a look at [per-deployment logging](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS72/Logging+Configuration#LoggingConfiguration-PerdeploymentLogging) or [logging profiles](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS72/Logging+Configuration#LoggingConfiguration-LoggingProfiles).

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to configure logging in JBoss and not in the deployment descriptor of the application you are deploying, then I think you will also need to set the host property org.jboss.as.logging.per-deployment=false. This tells JBoss to use the server logging config and not the application logging config.

And I think JBoss does support Log4J, at least according to page 340 of the following JBoss Admin Doc: [Administration and Configuration Guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.3/pdf/Administration_and_Configuration_Guide/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform-6.3-Administration_and_Configuration_Guide-en-US.pdf)